# Decode MJPEG video and convert it to RGB format efficently on android

Tags: android, video, decoding, mjpeg

I need to decode an MJPEG video stream from USB camera and convert the frames to RGB color format for further processing in opencv.
I can access the MJPEG frames from the stream but I am unable to decode them efficiently. I tried Mediacodec but it doesnt support mjpeg on my device. I also tried lipjpeg-turbo but i want hardware accelrated decoder.

Comment: Then why dont you buy one?

Comment: buy what? any links or reference would be appreciated

Comment: `hardware accelrated decoder`

Comment: i couldnt find any hardware accelrated decoder for sale anywhere